# How would I make a post to mongodb with an aurelia trigger?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aurelia

I want to be able to submit my input to MongoDB via a post route, but it seems like Aurelia is interfering with it and not letting the post route go through like I want. Is there a way to do this that I'm not seeing?

It seems like the click.delegate is running and causing the POST method to not run.

```
<form action="/add_item" method="POST">
        <input type="text" value="" name="listItem" value.bind="todoDescription">
        <button click.delegate="addTodo()" type="submit">Add Todo</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the event to bubble up return `true;` from the `addTodo()` function.

In your ViewModel:

```
addTodo() {
   //your logic here
   return true;
}
```

From Aurelia’s [binding documentation](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/basics#dom-events)

> Aurelia will automatically call preventDefault() on events handled with delegate or trigger binding. Most of the time this is the behavior you want. To turn this off, return true from your event handler function.

Allowing this event to bubble will post the form with the default submit behaviour, but that postback to the server. An alternative to not do the postback is to do the post from within the `addTodo()` function using [fetch api](https://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/http-services).

Comment: This would work if I didn't have the click delegate, I can put the return before the click delegate stuff, or after, but either the post method doesn't run or the click delegate doesn't run because of the return....any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if you did that, but you need to `return true` from the `addTodo()` function. If you dont return true from the function it won't work. But is there a reason why the `addTodo()` function isn't committing the post to `add-item`? As mentioned by pavsaund use the fetch client to post the todo item.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @Chameleon, what does the addTodo() function look like on your view model?